# Which of the following statements are true..?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the entire function $f(z)=1+z+z^{20}$ and $g(z)=e^z,z\in \mathbb{C}$ Which of the following statements are true ?

$1)$$\lim_{|z|\to \infty}|f(z)|=\infty$

$2)$$\lim_{|z|\to \infty}|g(z)|=\infty$

$3)$$f^{-1}(\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\le R\})$ is bounded for every $R>0$

$4)$$g^{-1}(\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\le R\})$ is bounded for every $R>0$

## My attempt  : option $1$ is only  correct  option

option 2)  is false  $lim_{x \rightarrow  -\infty}   e^{-x}  =  0$

option $3$ and $4$   are  contradiction of lioville  thorem so  it will be false

is  its  True ??

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: What's $x$ in the first two equations?

Comment: @Andrei i have  edits its

Comment: 3,4 do not contradict Liouville

Comment: The existence of root bounds shows that 3) is true, $z^{20}+z+1=w$ implies that $|z|\le 2+|w|=2+R$, with some work $|z|\le\sqrt[19]{2+R}$.

Comment: I understood the explanations of 1,2,3. Why (4) is false? @zhw

Comment: @Unknownx $g^{-1}(\{1\}) = 2\pi i\mathbb Z$ for example.